# Exercise:Prove function is bounded from below using Holder-estimate and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, holder-spaces

> Assume sequence of functions $\;f_n(x)\in W^{1,2}_{loc}
>  ((l^n_{-},l^n_{+});\mathbb R^m)\;$ and a function $f:(c,d)\rightarrow
>  \mathbb R^m\;$such that
>
> - $\;\lim_{n\to \infty} l^n_{-}=c\;\;\;\lim_{n\to \infty} l^n_{+}=d\;$
> - $\;f_n(x)\to f(x)\;$ uniform on bounded intervals $\;\forall x \in (c,d)\;$
>
> Note that $\;-\infty \le c \lt d \le +\infty\;$. Also consider a
>   continuous non-negative function $\;G:\mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb
>  R\;$ which satisfy:
>
> $\;\vert G(f_1)-G(f_2) \vert \le \varepsilon\;$ when $\;\vert f_1-f_2
>  \vert \le δ\;\; \forall f_1,f_2\;$ for some $\;δ\gt 0\;$ and
>   $\;\varepsilon \gt 0\;$
>
> If $\;f\in C^{0,\frac{1}{2}}\;$ i.e $\;\vert f(x_1)-f(x_2) \vert \le
>  \sqrt {2σ}{\vert x_1-x_2\vert}^{\frac{1}{2}} \;\;\forall x_1,x_2$,
>   show that $\;G(f(x))\ge \varepsilon\;\;\forall x\in
>  (x_n-\frac{δ^2}{2σ},x_n+\frac{δ^2}{2σ})\;$

**My attempt:**

All I have done is noticing that $\;x\in
 (x_n-\frac{δ^2}{2σ},x_n+\frac{δ^2}{2σ})\;$ is equivalent to $\;\sqrt {2σ} {\vert x-x_n \vert}^{\frac{1}{2}} \lt δ\;$ but it seems impossible to me to connect it to the Holder estimation for $\;f\;$. In addition I believe that from the condition for $\;G\;$ I could get some information about $\;G(f_n)\;$ and so using the fact that $\;G(f_n) \to G(f)\;$,I might prove the exercise but again I have no clue how!

I've been stuck to this exercise for more than a day, so I came here desperately seeking an answer or hints.I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you missing a term $G(f(x_n))$ somewhere in the claim?

Comment: (or some statement about $G(f_n(.))$?)

Comment: @Thomas No, I mentioned $\;G(f_n(x))\;$ because I believe that by condition for $\;G\;$ i.e. $\;\vert G(f_1)-G(f_2) \vert \le \varepsilon\;$, I could get some information about $\;G(f_n(x))\;$ and then using the fact that $\;G(f_n(x)) \to G(f)\;$ , I might prove the ex. But again all this could be all wrong

Comment: With what you have written down (in the yellow box) you could just choose $G\equiv 0$ and every condition is fullfilled, but certainly not the claim. Also there is nothing known about $G(f_n)$, so you cannot conclude anything  about $G(f)$ from $f_n$. Finally there is no relation of $G$ to any given data. Some prerequisite is missing or the statement is plain false (see $G\equiv 0$)